# Angular 5 service get re-instantiated

Tags: angular5, ionic4

I have two separate module loaded by lazy load and I am trying to pass some data between them and I do so by a service and the a service should be a singleton right ? but when i inject the service it get instantiated why?

here is the code for the first component

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { LocationService } from '../services/location.service';
import {Location} from '../shared/location';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-about',
  templateUrl: 'about.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['about.page.scss']
})
export class AboutPage {
  country :string;
  city :string;
  constructor(public locationService: LocationService){ }


  locationSelected(){

    let newLocation =  {country: this.country,city: this.city};
    this.locationService.location = newLocation;
    console.log(this.locationService.location);
  }
}
```

and this is the second component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {LocationService} from '../Services/location.service';
import { PrayerTimeService } from '../services/prayer-time.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss']
})

export class HomePage implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  prayerTime = {
    Asr : "15:48 (AST)",
    Dhuhr : "12:29 (AST)",
    Fajr : "04:36 (AST)",
    Isha : "20:23 (AST)",
    Maghrib : "19:02 (AST)",
    Sunrise : "05:56 (AST)"
  }
  constructor(private prayerTimeService: PrayerTimeService, public locationService : LocationService){}

  ngOnInit(){
    console.log(this.locationService.location);
    this.getPrayerTimes();
  }


  getPrayerTimes(){
    this.prayerTimeService.getTimes(this.locationService.location.country, this.locationService.location.city).subscribe((data) => {
      this.prayerTime = data.data[0].timings;
      console.log(this.prayerTime);
    });
  }
}
```

and this the parent module which provide the service

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule, RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import { LocationService } from './Services/location.service';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {AboutPageModule} from './about/about.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, HttpClientModule, FormsModule, AboutPageModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    LocationService,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

and this is the service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Location } from '../Shared/location';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LocationService {
  location : Location = new Location("","");
  constructor(private http : HttpClient) { console.log("new Service has Been created");}



}
```

Comment: Why do you think it gets re-instantiated?

Comment: Because I console log in ngOnInit and the value for the property location get reseted

Answer (score 0):

The service is not getting re-instatiated. The problem is that the call to the service in the ngOnInit happens before the method locationSelected() is called. Thus, the location will not be initialzed at this moment, bit shortly after that.

Comment: Actually the first component does not implement ngOnInit only the second component does and both of them are in a different route